# Recibir datos tipo string del plugin Date Range Picker a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datepicker

Tengo un `Date Range Picker` en `jQuery`, me funciona bien, el problema es que no he podido manipular las fechas que selecciono en mi `PHP`, ya que al ser `JS` y estar del lado del cliente, no capturo esa data en el input donde se muestra las fechas que me da `JS` (`Date Range Picker`).

Poseo también un simple `datepicker`, el cual si puedo manipular la data debido a que dicho input es llenado con php, y `jQuery` solo me da el diseño.
Pero en mi `Date Range Picker`, la data del input me la transmite el javascript.

HTML:

```
<form action="reporte.php" method="GET" class="form-inline" id="formConsulta">
<div class="form-group">
<div style="width:150%;"><input id="reportrange" name= "reportrange"></div></div><input name="consultar" type"submit" value"consultar" ></form>
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
</script>
```

En PHP no es posible algun: `$capturarRango=$_GET['#reportrange'];`

He probado algún método con `AJAX` pero no me corre.
¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Puedes agregar mayor información de tu pregunta, no entiendo si es necesario el GET para capturar la data

Comment: Lo que Necesito es que cuando el usuario del mi pagina consulte el form, la fecha en mi input (fecha mostrada por medio de jquery), se actualice a la que el usuario indico y no se que quede en la de defecto que viene de jquery